# Spawning and Argument List in Xcode Build

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any better solution rather than just shortening name and files for spawn error in XCode build. What is the threshold of argument list.

P.S.: I have more than 10k files in my xcode

Comment: You need to specify the dependency pods in the Podfile.

Comment: Can u show me with an example?